# Does chloride ion have its electron in hybrid orbitals?

Tags: bond, valence-bond-theory

Where are the electron valamce shell electron located in $\ce{Cl}^-$. Are they in pure $p$ and $s$ orbitals? Or are they in $sp^3$ hybrid orbital?

If the answer is that they are in pure orbitals i.e. they will not be symmetric anymore around the sphere of atom like it will in tetrahedral arrangement.

Comment: Hybridization occurs in our heads.

Comment: A full shell has spherical symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Atoms dont have hybrid orbitals.Only molecules have hybrid orbitals.So the added electron in the $Cl^{-}$ anion is in one of the p orbitals.

Comment: You know this because.....  And which orbital is this....